# Erros de conflito de versões ao Rodar projeto em Angular 4.2

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

Peguei um projeto em Angular para dar manutenção, porém está na versão do Angular CLI 4.2
Meu sistema esta com as versões de Node, Typescript e Angular cli nas seguintes versões:
`Angular CLI: 10.0.6`
`Node: 12.18.3`
`Typescript: Version 3.9.7`
`OS: win32 x64`

Meu projeto esta com as versões:

```
D:\VSTS\ASMS\ASMS.Angular4.2>ng --version
Your global Angular CLI version (10.0.6) is greater than your local
version (1.3.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
_ _ ____ _ ___
/ \ _ __ __ _ _ _| | __ _ _ __ / ___| | |_ _|
/ △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__| | | | | | |
/ ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | | | |___| |___ | |
/_/ \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_| \____|_____|___|
|___/
@angular/cli: 1.3.0
node: 12.18.3
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.7
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/common: 4.4.7
@angular/compiler: 4.4.7
@angular/core: 4.4.7
@angular/forms: 4.4.7
@angular/http: 4.4.7
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.7
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.7
@angular/router: 4.4.7
@angular/cli: 1.3.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.7
@angular/language-service: 4.4.7
```

Ao tentar rodar o projeto está me retornando os seguintes erros:

```
D:\VSTS\ASMS\ASMS.Angular4.2>ng serve
Your global Angular CLI version (10.0.6) is greater than your local
version (1.3.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\VSTS\ASMS\ASMS.Angular4.2\src\tsconfig.app.json'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\VSTS\ASMS\ASMS.Angular4.2\src\tsconfig.app.json'
at Object.statSync (fs.js:1016:3)
at AotPlugin._setupOptions (D:\VSTS\ASMS\ASMS.Angular4.2\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:62:16)
at new AotPlugin (D:\VSTS\ASMS\ASMS.Angular4.2\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:27:14)
at _createAotPlugin (D:\VSTS\ASMS\ASMS.Angular4.2\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:55:12)
at Object.exports.getNonAotConfig (D:\VSTS\ASMS\ASMS.Angular4.2\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:71:19)
at NgCliWebpackConfig.buildConfig (D:\VSTS\ASMS\ASMS.Angular4.2\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-config.js:29:37)
at Class.run (D:\VSTS\ASMS\ASMS.Angular4.2\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:43:98)
at D:\VSTS\ASMS\ASMS.Angular4.2\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:114:26
```

Não tenho experiência em Angular, por isso não tenho idéia de como resolver estes erros.

Alguuém tem idéia do que eu devo fazer?

Comment: Dentro do angular.json existe uma variavel "tsConfig", verifica se está apontando corretamente para o seu tsconfig.app.json. Com isso, verifique também se existe um tsconfig.app.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta apagar a pasta node_modules.
Depois apagar o arquivo package-lock.json
após isso verifique a versão do typescript na sua máquina, não no projeto, e deixe com a mesma versão sugerida no arquivo package.json.
Após isso rode `npm install`